# Talend Big Data Batch Spark Job with context ( https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TUP-16698)

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, talend

Can you guys help me with the below question...

I have a Talend BigData Batch Job(Spark) like below

tOracleInput ---> tMap --> tAvroOutput

I can run this job successfully by using my development Hadoop repository connection in the Spark configuration. However when I replace the Spark configuration with context variables and pass them at run time then the job is not running.. So I identified the problem that when I use the repository connection Talend is building a jar file like "hadoop-conf-"in the job libraries folder , and this jar file is haivng all hadoop configuration files like (core-site.xml,hive-site.xml,mapred-site.xml,yarn-site.xml...etc)

So now how can I pass these properties at runtime ? so that my job can run in Pre-Prod or Prod without any changes through Talend continous integration.

JIRA URL:- https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TUP-16698

Comment: Did you try copying the different sets of Hadoop conf files in different directories, e.g. `/etc/hadoop-prod/conf/` and the like, and adding the appropriate dir in the Driver CLASSPATH so that the Hadoop client libs find them at run-time, via `spark.driver.extraClassPath=/etc/hadoop-prod/conf/`?

Comment: Might also work with environment variable `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` -- at least it would work with `spark-submit` utility, but I'm not sure Talend honors that variable.

Comment: Thanks Samson.. I see your point. However Talend generates the code based on what we configure and it moves the artifacts to Pre-Prod & Prod through continuous integration. So I have no control at run-time except passing context variables.

Comment: Talend BigData w/ Spark is a **licenced** module, isn't it? So why don't you contact the Talend support directly?

Comment: Yeah.. that is what my option now. I am thinking that this is something basic which I am missing.. I will do that. Thanks Samson.

Comment: Side note: I heard from our Talend team that some of their issues with Spark jobs (especially Hadoop HA configuration properties) disappeared when they upgraded to the latest Talend release. And also that the Talend documentation about the Hadoop properties is very sparse (to remain polite).

Comment: I completely agree. I raised a support case and will post the answer once I am convinced.

Comment: Hello Samson.. looks like it is a new feature request for Talend and they are going to release in 6.4.1.. For now they are recommending to use separate repository connections for each cluster.. Still the case is open will update you if anything new .

Comment: _"I have no control at run-time except passing context variables."_ >> Can you set the value of an environment variable (with `tSetEnv` I guess) using a context variable? Can you set the value of Talend job properties (e.g. HDFS namenode address) using a context variable? If yes, then try to move all the XML config files used by Talend Studio (probably imported from Ambari or Cloudera Manager for your Dev cluster) to a different directory, set a Context var with the dir name, and set env var `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` with that ctx var. And "variabilize" all props that refer to cluster nodes.

Comment: We can pass the context variables but the spark job will run for an hour or so and fail with some weird error. however if I use repository it works fine. And one more way is use context variables + tlibraryload in the job with hadoop config jar file then job works fine.. However in sparkjob we cannot pass dynamic library at run-time. Here the JIRA link for the same issue. https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TUP-16698

Comment: OK, then could you edit your question and add a link to that JIRA, to make it easier for anyone who has the same issue and finds this post?